# Javascript & JQuery odd issue or what did I do wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for coping values from window to window that is working one way, but not another...

Working script:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#clickit').live({
        click: function() { 
            window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'].value = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'].value;
            window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'].value = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'].value;
            self.close();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Now I on this other script, what did I do wrong? I'm pulling my hair out here.

Not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#clickit').live({
        click: function() { 
            var thisservice = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'].value;
            var thisrate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'].value;
            var thatservice = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'].value;
            var thatrate = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'].value;
            $(thatrate) = $(thisrate);
            $(thatservice) = $(thisservice);
            self.close();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I've also tried..

```
$(thatrate).val() = $(thisrate).val();
$(thatservice).val() = $(thisservice).val();
```

And..

```
thatrate = thisrate;
thatservice = thisservice;
```

But this works:

```
var service = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'].value;
var rate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'].value;
window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'].value = service;
window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'].value = rate;
```

Am I not assigning the var correctly for the `window.opener`?

Comment: FYI, the syntax is `$(thatrate).val($(thisrate).val())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisservice = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'];
var thisrate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'];
var thatservice = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'];
var thatrate = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'];

thatrate.value = thatservice.value;
thatservice.value = thisservice.value;
```

or if you want to wrap the DOM objects with a jQuery object.

```
var thisservice = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'];
var thisrate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'];
var thatservice = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'];
var thatrate = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'];

$(thatrate).val( $(thatservice).val() );
$(thatservice).val( $(thisservice).val() );
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(thatrate).val($(thisrate).val());
$(thatservice).val($(thisservice).val());
```

The new value goes inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var thisservice = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'];
var thisrate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'];
var thatservice = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'];
var thatrate = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'];
thatrate.val(thisrate.val());
thatservice.val(thisservice.val());
```

Comment: Remember in your example `thatrate` is not a jQuery object but a native DOM object so `.val` would not work. User `.value` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your console will tell you: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

```
$(thatrate) = $(thisrate);
$(thatservice) = $(thisservice);
```

You should do it like this:

```
var thisservice = document.forms['GroundRates']['service'];
var thisrate = document.forms['GroundRates']['rate'];
var thatservice = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['service'];
var thatrate = window.opener.document.forms['orderForm']['rate'];

thatrate.value = thisrate.value
thatservice.value = thisservice.value;
```